# Default reorder when negative stock to keep zero inventory.

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm looking for a way to set a global reorder rule in Odoo 10 community, where if stock falls below zero it generates a draft PO for that stock... Instead of having to create a reorder rule for every product.

Anyone have any suggestions on how that could be accomplished?

Very much appreciated.